# How to display on a certain amount of data for a specific column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Consider the following table

`Dept  product  name  parts  WO
 32    aa       abc   11   1234
 32    aa       aas   18   2213
 32    bb       asd   16   3424
 32    aa       adf   19   1255
 32    cc       asa   10   7567
 32    aa       agd   11   1233
 31    ss       fsf   23   3434`

I have around 100 dept. in my table. What I want is that when the dept. is 32 and the product is "aa", I only want to display 30 parts or less. So in this case the total number of parts for aa is 59. So the first aa product has 11 parts and the next aa product has 18 parts so that's 29. It should now ignore all the other aa products.

Expected Output

`Dept  product  name  parts  WO
 32    aa       abc   11   1234
 32    aa       aas   18   2213
 32    bb       asd   16   3424
 32    cc       asa   10   7567
 31    ss       fsf   23   3434`

Appreciate any help provided.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `WO` is a primary key then use `SUM` window function to solve it.

```
SELECT yt.Dept, yt.product, yt.name, yt.parts, yt.WO
FROM yourtable yt
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT *, sum(y.parts) over (partition by y.dept order by y.parts) tsum
   FROM yourtable y
   WHERE y.product = 'aa'
) t ON yt.WO= t.WO
WHERE yt.dept != 32 or (yt.dept = 32 and t.tsum < 59) or (yt.dept = 32 and yt.product != 'aa')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use SUM() window function where you have to partition by dept and product

```
SELECT dept,
       product,
       name,
       parts,
       wo
  FROM (SELECT *, 
               SUM(parts) OVER (PARTITION BY dept, product ORDER BY name) rt
          FROM t
       ) t_rt
 WHERE rt <= 30
 ORDER BY dept DESC,
          product,
          wo
```

Result

```
dept    product name    parts   wo
32      aa      abc     11      1234
32      aa      aas     18      2213
32      bb      asd     16      3424
32      cc      asa     10      7567
31      ss      fsf     23      3434
```